# ruby iterate through sql results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to iterate through records found with sql and update them all.

I need to update a couple of thousand records and the requirements are complex enough that I search for the records by SQL. The code below works but is there a way of doing it without performing several thousand update statements?

```
users = User.find_by_sql "select e.id from users e inner join accounts a on a.id = e.account_id where e.account_id not in (1955,3083, 3869)"
users.each do |user|
  u = User.find(user.id)
  if u
    u.update_attribute(:last_name, 'X')
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you post whether you use Mysql, SQLite, etc? And your version of Rails/Ruby?

Comment: It's not clear why you need `find_by_sql` here. `User.joins(:accounts).where('users.account_id NOT IN (?)', [1955, 3083, 3869])` would generate the same query.

Comment: Hi Onebree. Using ruby 2, Rails 3.2 and mysql

Answer (score 2):

This would do the same thing as your code, but with a single `UPDATE`:

```
User.joins(:accounts)
  .where("users.account_id NOT IN (?)", [1955, 3083, 3869])
  .update_all(last_name: "X")
```

You can find the documentation for `update_all` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all).

Comment: In Rails 4, you can do: `User.where.not(account_id: [1955, 3083, 3869])`

Comment: And this won't update any other columns, ie `updated_at`. I usually like to set that to `Time.now`, depending on the situation.